# Can I post clearly losing answers to puzzles with the purpose of receiving suggestions to improve?

Tags: discussion

I did one of the Code Golf challenges this morning in order to practice my C++ ability. However, my code took up significantly more bytes compared to all the other answers. None of the answers were done in C++, so I didn't really have a comparison of what a good answer would look like. Would it have been reasonable to post my solution even though it was clearly wrong. I would like to practice code brevity and efficiency, but am not sure if this is the place to learn or to demonstrate.